# What kind of chart to use for showing big stock transactions?

Tags: data-visualization, descriptive-statistics

I have a requirement to write a program to show a list of stock buyers with their transaction data across time. That is,

```
2016-08-01:
buyer 1 => 3,000 shares
buyer 2 => 4,000 shares
...
buyer 200 => 1,000,000 shares

2016-08-01:
buyer 1 => 0 shares
...
buyer 201 => 1,000 shares
```

There are a number of scenarios:

- the number of shares can vary greatly among buyers
- some buyers may have sold all their shares and they only have data for specific dates
- there can be many buyers

A specific requirement is to be able to highlight big changes in the number of shares per buyer across time.

What is the appropriate chart for this? I tried the Google Line Chart but since the number of buyers is somewhat big and the number of shares is somewhat similar for them, the lines are plotted closely together. There is also the issue of the spread of the number of shares for different buyers.